# StackOverflowError when try create new object of inherit class in superclass

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am newbie in Java. Can anyone explain to me why it show StackOverflowError ?

```
public class MainClass {

    static Start st = new Start();

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        st.start();
    }
}


public class Start {

    Generator objGenerator = new Generator();

    void start() {      
        objGenerator.generator();
    }
}


public class Generator extends Start {

    void generator() {
        //...
    }
}
```

If Generator class is not inherited from class Start, everything is ok, but why ?

Comment: Could you show us the code in `void generator()`? (Or does it crash with nothing in the function? I'm not an expert.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Generator` inherits from `Start`

```
class Generator extends Start
```

And `Start` creates a `Generator` on construction:

```
Generator objGenerator = new Generator();
```

Which is the same as the following:

```
public class Start {

    Generator objGenerator;

    public Start() {
         objGenerator = new Generator();
    }
}
```

---

1. `Start` has constructor that runs `objGenerator = new Generator()`.
2. This calls the constructor for `Generator`.
3. The first thing that the constructor for `Generator` does is call `super()`.
4. `super()` is default constructor for `Start`.
5. GOTO 1.

Answer (score 1):

When an Instance of `Generator` is created, the constructor of `Start` is called because `Generators` `extends` `Start`. This is called constructor chaining.

However, when you call the constructor of `start` you also have a variable thats call new `Generator`...

You create a `Generator` that is a `Start` that creates a `Generator` that is a `Start`... and its goes on until your `stack overflows`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the StackOverflow error is because the recursive instantiation of objects does not terminate. The recursive object intstantiation is as follows.

Step 1: static Start st = new Start();

Step 2: Instantiating a Start object requires instantiating a Generator object due to the initialization of the member variable objGenerator.

```
Generator objGenerator = new Generator();
```

Step 3: Since Generator is a subclass of Start, instantiating a Generator object requires instantiating Start object, which is going back to step 2.

So in effect you are in a infinite loop going back and forth between step 2 and step 3. Upon hitting the stack limit, the StackOverflow exception is thrown.